# NServiceBus: Disable retry when exception is encountered

Tags: nservicebus

We are using NServiceBus 6.4, and we've already disabled retries by setting the delayed and immediate to 0. However, when an exception is caught, are retry is still triggered. How can we completely disable retry even when there's an exception?

```
            config.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
            recoverability.Delayed(delayed => { delayed.NumberOfRetries(0); });
            recoverability.Immediate(immediate => { immediate.NumberOfRetries(0); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on disabling retries can be found here:

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-immediate-retries#disabling
- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-delayed-retries#disabling-through-code

It's exactly what you did. So it should not work anymore.

Comment: if immediate retry is turned off  does this affect delayed retry?

Comment: You turn off immediate retries by setting the number of retries to 0. It does exactly that. The result is that it goes into delayed retries immediately. Except if you turn those off as well, then the result is that error messages go into the error queue immediately.